# Twitter not displaying summary_large_image card correctly

Tags: facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

I'm trying to get the large image card to work with a website. The metadata is being read correctly, but it's displaying the small summary card, instead.

My metadata:

```html
<!-- Twitter Card -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta property="twitter:domain" content="volkischexe.com">
<meta property="twitter:url" content="/germania/index.php">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Germania: An Introduction">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="...">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="http://volkischexe.com/res/cards/germania-intro.png?605a78eeba1aa">

<!-- OpenGraph Card -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="/germania/index.php">
<meta property="og:title" content="Germania: An Introduction">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://volkischexe.com/res/cards/germania-intro.png?605a78eeba1ae">
<meta property="og:description" content="...">

<!-- HTML Meta -->
<title>Germania: An Introduction</title>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://volkischexe.com/germania/">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://volkischexe.com/res/cards/germania-intro.png?605a78eeba1b1">
<meta property="og:title" content="Germania: An Introduction">
<meta property="og:description" content="...">  
<meta name="description" content="...">
<title>Germania: An Introduction</title>
```

Twitter seems to see my metadata correctly, too:
[image]

What am I missing here?

ETA: The validator doesn't show my cards correctly, but if I actually tweet them, they show up just fine. So there's something going on with the validator, but as long as my cards show up on Twitter, I'm good.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that could be stopping Twitter from sharing a large card for your site:

- A couple of your twitter meta settings use “content,” but twitter wants “name.”
- Your site is redirecting to https, so use the secure version for the URLs in your meta information.
- It’s good to include the image sizes for Facebook.
- And you don’t need the index.php file name – your server will automatically serve up the index.php file.

Try replacing your code with this:

```html
<!-- OpenGraph Card -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://volkischexe.com/germania/">
<meta property="og:title" content="Germania: An Introduction">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://volkischexe.com/res/cards/germania-intro.png?605e46b26abc5">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
<meta property="og:description" content="From where does the modern Western world derive its values and morals?">

<!-- Twitter Card -->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="volkischexe.com">
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://volkischexe.com/germania/">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Germania: An Introduction">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="From where does the modern Western world derive its values and morals?">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://volkischexe.com/res/cards/germania-intro.png?605e46b26abc1">
```

One thing (that may or may not be impacting Twitter) is the start of your page is missing DOCTYPE and some other stuff:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Germania: An Introduction</title>
        <meta name="description" content="From where does the modern Western world derive its values and morals?">

        <link rel="preload" href="/res/AndBasR.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
        <link rel="preload" href="/res/CelticHand.ttf" as="font" type="font/ttf" crossorigin>
        <link rel="preload" href="/res/Norse-Bold.otf" as="font" type="font/otf" crossorigin>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/res/main.css">

        <script src="/res/main.js"></script>
```

One thing with the [Twitter card validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) — sometimes is doesn’t rescrape your site when you click the Preview Card button. You may need to restart your browser (closed and reopened) and rescrape a couple of times to get it to load the new version.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - fixed the HTTPS on the image URLs and the :url tag (which is programmatically generated), as well as the "property" vale in my twitter tags.. Still getting the summary card, though. Third-party validators render the large card properly. (example: https://en.rakko.tools/tools/9/)

Comment: Your page is still missing the `<meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` meta tags in the head. I can’t say for sure, but I suspect you need those for Twitter.

Comment: Just added that and tried a fresh URL - no dice.

Comment: For some reason, the *Twitter Validator* doesn’t want to display how your site will look if someone tweets it. I copied your code to my server, changing all the addresses to my URL, including a copy of the image and the card showed up. When I changed the image URL to your server, Twitter wouldn’t display the card. It’s probably not critical as when I enter your address into a tweet, the large card does shows up.

Comment: thanks - I tweeted a link to my site yesterday myself and it did in fact show the large card. So I guess there's just something wonky with the validator. Thanks for testing!!